# В PyQt у виджета QMediaPlayer не воспроизводится звук?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qmediaplayer

Я пишу аудиоплеер на *PyQt*, использую `QMediaPlayer` для этого, но когда я пытаюсь воспроизвести трек, ничего не случется. 
Ошибок никаких не выдает.И так в любой программе, которую я не писал бы.

Я скорее всего не вижу чего-то очевидного, но все равно прошу помощи.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Кто отправил сигнал')

        self.player = QMediaPlayer()

        self.button_1 = QPushButton(self)
        self.button_1.move(90, 40)
        self.button_1.setText("Кнопка")
        self.button_1.clicked.connect(self.run)
        self.link = 'Resource\\mus\\barbariki-s-dnyom-rozhdeniya-mp3.mp3'

    def run(self):
        url = QtCore.QUrl(self.link)
        self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(url))
        # тут запускаю проигрывание, но ничего не происходит
        self.player.play()


def except_hook(cls, exception, traceback):
    sys.__excepthook__(cls, exception, traceback)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()

    ex.show()
    sys.excepthook = except_hook
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Файл mp3 не могу загрузить сюда, на сайт

Comment: Прошу, я уже 2й день пытаюсь понять, что не так, почему нет звука.

Comment: Владимир у вас все нормально. Попробуйте заменить строку `self.link = 'Resource\\mus\\barbariki-s-dnyom-rozhdeniya-mp3.mp3'`    на   `self.link = 'Resource/mus/barbariki-s-dnyom-rozhdeniya-mp3.mp3'`. При этом что вы запускаете `main.py` из папки где лежит `main.py`, В этой же папке у вас каталог `Resource`, а в нем каталог `mus` , в котором лежит `barbariki-s-dnyom-rozhdeniya-mp3.mp3`

Comment: Пробовал, и полный путь к файлу тоже указывал, не знаю, что еще может быть

Comment: Ошибки ни какие не вылазиют

Comment: Владимир, у меня ваш код работает, это уже хорошо. Приложение запускайте в CMD/консоли/терминале. Проверьте ваш файл `.mp3` - просто кликните по нему, играет? Положите его рядом с `main.py` и запустите `python main.py` , играет?

Comment: mp3 играет, положил егов папку с *.py (кодом), все также.

Comment: Попробовал через cdm, появилось это сообщение: defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"

Comment: попробуйте почитать https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyqt%5D+or+%5Bpyqt4%5D+or+%5Bpyqt5%5D+or+%5Bpyqt6%5D+or+%5Bpyside2%5D+or+%5Bpyside6%5D+no+service+found+for+-+%22org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer%22

Comment: + https://www.google.com/search?q=pyqt+defaultServiceProvider%3A%3ArequestService()%3A+no+service+found+for+-+%22org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer%22&oq=pyqt+defaultServiceProvider%3A%3ArequestService()%3A+no+service+found+for+-+%22org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.1050j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8